# Cascade Update Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE supplier
( supplier_id numeric(10) not null,
supplier_name varchar2(50),
contact_name varchar2(50),
CONSTRAINT supplier_pk PRIMARY KEY (supplier_id)
);

CREATE TABLE products
( product_id numeric(10) not null,
supplier_id numeric(10),
CONSTRAINT fk_supplier
FOREIGN KEY (supplier_id)
REFERENCES supplier(supplier_id)
ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

I need to cascade update the the primary key in 'supplier' and hence foreign key in 'products'. I am thinking of a cursor with a trigger to update child table, but cannot figure out how that could be

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure that I understand what you are trying to do.  What `update` would you be cascading?  Are you saying that you want to be able to update a `supplier_id` in `supplier` and have that update cascade to the `products` table?  That's possible but rather convoluted.  Normally, you'd want your primary key to be immutable in order to avoid that sort of thing.

Comment: @JustinCave Yes, but it happened that I need to update the primary key "supplier_id" and cascade the update to all child tables (cascade).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, you'd structure your data model such that primary keys are immutable in order to avoid the problem in the first place.

If you absolutely need to allow for cascading updates, you probably want to use Tom Kyte's [cascading update script](http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2009/10/httpasktomoraclecomtkyteupdatecascade.html).  For each table, this will dynamically generate a package and three triggers (before statement, before row, and after statement) that will implement all the logic needed to cascade the update.  This is likely to be vastly more efficient (and more accurate) than anything that a single developer would knock together.  Just because of the rather large number of objects that need to be created, though, it's a pretty heavy overhead to maintain.