# Oracle database - determine what table triggered a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle12c

I am working with Oracle Express 12c. One of the tables I created has an associated trigger which prevents it from directly updating one of its columns. But it fires even when another table, which should have this kind of access, tries to do it.

For example:

I have tables A and B, and B has a foreign key that links it to A. I purposefully added one of the attributes from A to B. One trigger, let's call it UPD_FROM_B, prevents B from updating this attribute. Another, UPD_FROM_A, should update this attribute on B if it is updated on A. Now UPD_FROM_B prevents UPD_FROM_A from doing what it is supposed to.

---

Or through a working example:

There are two tables: **customer** and **order**. **Customer** can have multiple orders, but one **order** has only one customer. For the sake of the project, I had to put *customer_name* on the order, even though every order has *customer_id* as foreign key.

One trigger - **UPD_NAME_ORDER** prevents **order** from updating the
*customer_name*, and the other - **UPD_NAME_CUST** updates this column in the appropriate row of the **order** table whenever *customer_name* is updated in **customer**

---

How can I determine which table triggered the action and allow UPDATE for one, but still prevent it from the other?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that a table "tries to do?" Do you mean that there can be another trigger on another table trying to update your table? Please try to post a [mcve] to help people to understand your need and give you an answer,

Comment: @Aleksej I added an example which should be clear enough. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I believe you can not determine who fired your trigger, but maybe you'll find something interesting [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25072979/cascade-update-oracle)

Comment: Your "example" is unclear. Which table owns which trigger? Your example sounds like a hypothetical that you are considering, based on misunderstanding of how triggers work; not an existing scenario. If not, then post the DDL or query the catalog view ALL_TRIGGERS to find out.

Comment: @mustaccio yes, but DML statements are called upon tables. UPDATE table_name SET etc. That's what I was saying.

Comment: @codenheim I am not that proficient in English to know how to translate exact business entities here, so I wanted to avoid further confusion. And, yes, I am pretty new to triggers so I am not surprised I mixed something up.

Comment: @mustaccio - While I agree with your statement in context of his question, your statement isn't strictly true. Oracle supports triggers on specific columns as well as more granular enforcement logic using the ON and WHEN clauses of the trigger, so one UPDATE might pass and one might not.

Comment: @codenheim I don't come from an English speaking background. My business model contains names that are outdated even in my own language and I can't translate them. I could try to come up with relevant analogies, but am afraid that I would make a mistake that would cause more harm than good. That is why I try to keep it simple by, yes, making this sound hypothetical. Or conceptual, if I may.

Comment: @mustaccio - C'mon. If you are going to be pedantic and sarcastic, at least be correct. I was trying to be polite while pointing out your incorrect statement. What I meant by "context" was more "for the purposes of his question" in conceding that your incorrect comment was still applicable to him. Sorry you got defensive, but it is still incorrect. The statement _If you have a trigger that prevents update statements, all update statements will be prevented by it_ and that is still wrong.

Comment: @codenheim I understand. I will try to come up with an adequate analogy for my example and edit this question when I get some rest :) I understand that I am responsible for the clarity of my questions and the feedback. Thank you very much for your constructive suggestions.

Comment: @dzenesiz - Is your goal to implement UPDATE CASCADE on the parent table while disallowing update of the child record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At face value, the way I know to do this is to use a package variable as a gate key and share it between the 2 triggers. Trigger A will set the state variable before its nested update of B. Trigger B will check if A set the var, if so, the update succeeds, if not, then B knows A is not the caller, and it should block the update.

Also, I assume your intention is to implement an "*UPDATE CASCADE*" trigger to update the child record foreign key values based on the parent update, preserving the relationship while updating the FK value. If so, you have to be careful with this approach, it will only work correctly if you disallow multi-row updates.

First a package and state var:

```
CREATE PACKAGE IsUpdating IS
  A number;
END;
```

At top of trigger A do something like below. The exception handler is a "finally" block that always executes to avoid leaving the package variable in an invalid state in case of an error on the update:

```
CREATE TRIGGER A_UPD_CASCADE after update on A for each row
BEGIN
    IsUpdating.A := 1;
    update B set B.FKID = :new.FKID WHERE B.FKID = :old.FKID;
    IsUpdating.A := 0;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        IsUpdating.A := 0;
        RAISE;
END;
```

Inside trigger B do this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER B_UPD_CASCADE before update on B
BEGIN
    if IsUpdating.A != 1 then
        -- Disallow update since it is coming from B alone
        RAISE;
    end if;
END;
```

The pitfall with CASCADE UPDATE is with multi-row parent updates in a single statement, Oracle will execute the trigger for each parent value, causing some child values to update multiple times based on chained before and after values.

Comment: I won't be implementing UPDATE CASCADE, but I believe this should work. I'll take your advice and add a more appropriate example to my question anyway. I'll test this shortly, so I can mark your answer as accepted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I think you must change your trigger UPD_FROM_B only. 
Firstly you select value of column from table A when parent key and foreign key are equal, then compare this value to value of column from table B. If this value equal your trigger allow to do this updating, else not. You write this code as follow:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UPD_FROM_B before update on B
DECLARE
 val A.upd_column%TYPE; 
BEGIN
    select A.upd_column into val
    where A.ID=B.FKID
    if val=B.upd_column then

        RAISE;
    else ......
    end if;
END;
```